# What is the name of the set obtained by multiplying a given number by any rational?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, rational-numbers

Given a number, is there a name for the set where each element results of multiplying this number by a rational?

For a given $ n \in \mathbb N $:

$$ \{ r \cdot n \mid  r \in \mathbb Q \} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any sort of object $x$ for which it makes sense to multiply $x$ by rational numbers, you can call the set in question simply *"the set of rational multiples of $x$"*, or sometimes, *"the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $x$"*.

However, it should be pointed out that no matter what (non-zero) natural number $n$ you choose, the set of rational multiples of $n$ is exactly the set of rational numbers, i.e. $\{r\cdot n\mid r\in\mathbb{Q}\}=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I bet this last statement is easy to prove, but is it related to any author?, does it have a name?

Comment: Is it also true for any $ n \in \mathbb Q $ ?

Comment: @nightcod3r: Yes, it is true for any $n\in\mathbb{Q}$ (other than $n=0$). However it is such a minor observation that there will be no specific author or name associated to it. Observe that starting with a non-zero $n\in\mathbb{Q}$, for any rational number $q$ you want, the number $\frac{q}{n}$ is also a rational number, and if we choose $r=\frac{q}{n}$, then we get that $r\cdot n=\frac{q}{n}\cdot n= q$, so that $\{r\cdot n\mid r\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ contains any rational number $q$ you want. Since it also cannot contain anything except rational numbers, it must be exactly equal to $\mathbb{Q}$.